# Get private key from .pk file

Tags: private-key

I have a `.pk` file that should contain a private key. I can not find any information about this file format. Is it similar to `.pkcs12`?

How can I retrieve the private key from this kind of file?

Answer (score 0):

According to [fileinfo.com](http://fileinfo.com/extension/pk) `.pk` is not a known certificate store file extension. Maybe you could ask from the source of the file why they named it like that.

Check if it's pkcs12 file by trying to output info about the file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in yourfile.pk
```

If it's pkcs12 then you can export the private key from it with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourfile.pk -nocerts -nodes privatekey.pem
```

---

Obviously, your file is in PEM format. You can check the file in text editor for  **-----BEGIN** texts to see what's inside. Cand you see **BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY** or **BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY** or **BEGIN PRIVATE KEY** text in the file? Are there also certificate(s) in the same file, i.e. can you see **BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY** or **BEGIN PUBLIC KEY** once or multiple times?

You can remove a passphrase from RSA private key like this:

```
openssl rsa -in yourfile.pk -out privatekey.pem
```

Comment: I get errors ""error:0D0680A8" and "error:0D07803A", which according to https://www.ssl247.com/kb/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting/apache/errors-asn1-encoding-routine-apache "This error is due to an invalid certificate format "

Comment: I got new information about this .pk file: contains an RSA key and that it's possible that I need to provide a password(which I already have), while extracting the key from the .pk file.

Comment: (sorry for double post, I hit Enter too soon and I cannot edit the comment yet)
I got new information about this .pk file:
- .pk is not a certificate file extension, but it might contain one that has an RSA key
- it's possible that I need to provide a password(which I already have), while extracting the RSA key